# Running ivs broadcast services in node server without browser

Tags: amazon-ivs

I'm trying to create a broadcasting app with aws ivs service. I'm using reactjs as client side application where I can subscribe the streams for both audio and video. Now I'm trying to move the broadcast service (ie, publising the stream from stage to channel to view in hls link) alone from react front-end to node service. But facing lot of issues.

1. Tried to install sdk package to access the stage and get the audio and video streams and send the it to channel but Couldn,t able to import the sdk methods for stage in node server.
2. Tried to use puppeteer to join the stage and get the stream, got the stream but on accessing the channel with ingestendpoint and stream key getting 400 bad request with response message
   {
   "code": 1013,
   "message": "SDP offer does not support mandatory H264 codec"
   }
   in puppeteer browser.
   So is there a way to move the server side to braodcast the streams in channel from stage?